# Getting a distinct set of values from objects in a list in python

Tags: python, list

Let's say that I have the following list consisting of a set of objects:

```
people = [("John","Smith"), ("Jane","Doe"), ("Jane","Smith")]
```

The objects are created via a separate class which has `person.getFirstName` and `person.getLastName` defs.

How can I parse the list such that I end up with a separate list of values consisting of

```
 uniqueNames = ["Smith","Doe"]
```

Answer (score 3):

using list comprehension might do what you need:

```
>>> people = [("John","Smith"), ("Jane","Doe"), ("Jane","Smith")]
>>> uniqueNames = list(set(i[1] for i in people))
>>> uniqueNames
['Smith', 'Doe']
```